# How to take screenshots using marmalade with c++?

Tags: c++, screenshot, marmalade

I searched along the documentation and found nothing, then after searching on google i found this glReadPixels and i guess i may be able to take screenshots.

I need to create a facebookdialog with an image so im using this lines:

```
static s3eFBRequest* req = s3eFBRequest_WithGraphPath(MultiLoginScene::getSession(), "me/photos", "POST");
s3eFBRequest_AddParamString(req, "picture", XXX);
```

XXX is a const char* that would be this screenshot I need to take and then i will just send the request.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Marmalade website is gone.  Unfortunate the answer wasn't posted here, but briefly:

```
int w = s3eSurfaceGetInt(S3E_SURFACE_WIDTH);
int h = s3eSurfaceGetInt(S3E_SURFACE_HEIGHT);

int dataSize = w * h * 3;
unsigned char *framebuffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(dataSize * sizeof(unsigned char));
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, framebuffer);
flipVertical(framebuffer, w, h);

CIwImage image;
image.SetFormat(CIwImage::BGR_888);
image.SetWidth(w);
image.SetHeight(h);
image.SetBuffers(framebuffer, dataSize);
image.SavePng(filename);

free(framebuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to search on marmalade site for these kinda feature first. There's already a very nice written answer [here](https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/3473/save-texturesurfacescreenshot-to-a-image-file.html).

PS: Please stop posting multiple questions asking same thing.